# nodejs fs eacces permission

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, permissions, fs

I've just run into a strange problem with fs reading a file.

I have node application run from a deployment manager (strongloop strong-pm) as the following user "strong-pm".

No matter what permissions I give to the file I'm trying to open throug the node app, I get

```
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);

worker:1 Error: EACCES, permission denied '/root/my_dir/file.txt'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:286:15)
```

I've tried everything:
`sudo chown -R strong-pm:strong-pm /root/my_dir`
`sudo chmod -R 777 /root/my_dir`
`sudo chmod 777 /root/my_dir/file.txt`
adding the strong-pm to a group
then adding that group to the directory...

Still no luck.. any ideas?

Thanks!

---

System: Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on DigitalOcean

Comment: Does everything look correct when you run `ls -l /root/my_dir/file.txt`?

Comment: yep... it looked all good... usual permissions, usual user/group

Comment: And what permissions has `/root` itself?

Comment: root has root:root for everything... would that be the issue? I thought that if I made the parent directory accessible then it would work?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying it inside node, try to switch to that user and read the file:

```
su strong-pm
cat /root/my_dir/file.txt
```

If that works, make sure node is running using that user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.{otherPATH}/root/my_dir/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like the issue was that the /root directory was protected and so subdirectories were not accessible by node somehow